# calling joblib Parallel in a class method creates N instances of everything, instead of just function object

Tags: python, matplotlib, parallel-processing, joblib

I tried to find answers to this elsewhere but couldn't locate it.

```py
import numpy as np

class Item:
     def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        # item attributes

     def plot(self):
        print("plotting")
        # matplotlib plot

class Video:
    def __init__(self):
        # load preprocessing
        # load pytorch model
        print("loaded pytorch model")
        self.items = []

    def process(self):
        # find items
        names_found = np.arange(7)
        for name in names_found:
            # do some processing
            self.items.append(Item(name))
```

Now say I want to write out plots in parallel

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

v = test.Video()
v.process()

Parallel(n_jobs=7)(delayed(item.plot)() for item in v.items)
```

but it outputs

```sh
# output
"loaded pytorch model"
"loaded pytorch model"
"loaded pytorch model"
"loaded pytorch model"
"loaded pytorch model"
"loaded pytorch model"
"loaded pytorch model"

"plotting"
"plotting"
"plotting"
"plotting"
"plotting"
"plotting"
"plotting"
```

as though it's loading everything in memory for each iteration. How do I parallelise just the plotting component here so it doesn't blow up memory etc. with N instances of the model.